# Does major garbage collection require memory outside of the JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

During major garbage collection, does the machine require memory outside of the JVM allocated amount?

The reason I'm asking is we have a box with 6 gigs of ram, running 2 jvm's that use around 2.6 gigs of heap/memory each. Sometimes right before major garbage collection(concurrent mark sweep and compact) there is only a few hundred megs of free memory throughout the entire ram.

I was just wondering if more ram is required in these kind of situations, theoretically.

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: It's kind of up to the JVM implementer.  But note that pretty much all JVMs have a regular C heap over and above Java GC heap.

Comment: @AlexRodrigues Hotspot 64bit

Comment: @HotLicks Got it, I guess I'm curious, even without this situation, how much memory the garbage collector takes.

Comment: @user3457245 I'd imagine that the JVM's max memory usage is exactly what you set it at. In your case, you have 2 JVMs with 2.6 gigs = 5.2 gigs for those, plus overhead for your OS, so you'd have only a few hundred left...

Comment: The GC needs storage for various flags and tables.  At a minimum there must be a set of flags in each object (in the object header) that contain the object "color".  Then, for efficiency, I think most GC schemes use reference lists -- lists of addresses to be checked -- so that addressing RAM is not quite so random (since random is inefficient).  Hard to guess how big the lists could get, but a wild thumb-suck would be that worst case they'd be 10% of the size of object store.  Some schemes also need lists of to-be-reclaimed objects, etc.  Generally, all but the color flags would be in C heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"jvm's that use around 2.6 gigs of heap/memory each".

Looks like your Xmx is 2.6 GB. But Xmx(Heap Memory) is not the only Memory Area used by JVM so memory used by 1 JVM will be 2.6 + and u may feel like memory outside of JVM is used.

The JVM memory consists of the following segments:

- Heap Memory, which is the storage for Java objects
- Non-Heap Memory, which is used by Java to store loaded classes and
  other meta-data
- JVM code itself, JVM internal structures, loaded profiler agent code
  and data, etc.

[image: Memory Structure]

[Details.](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp)